# Navigating in the Nautilus 3.10.1 side pane using the keyboard

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys, filemanager

I would like to be able to navigate the main file manager window as well as the Nautilus (3.10.1) side pane using just the keyboard (arrow keys etc.).

How do I switch between being able to navigate in the side pane and in the main window using the keyboard? That is, how do I switch between the area where the arrow keys are currently active for navigation?

For example, in the below picture how do I switch between being able to navigate "Places" (Home, Desktop etc.) and the directories (Documents, Downloads etc.)?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can toggle between navigating the side pane and the main window (using the arrow keys) by pressing the <kbd>F6</kbd> key. So,

<kbd>F6</kbd> and then any  <kbd>arrow keys</kbd> : Navigate main window.

<kbd>F6</kbd> and then  <kbd>up/down</kbd> : Navigate side pane.

Comment: That allows me to move the "focus" in the bookmark bar, but when I press <kbd>Enter<\kbd> to confirm, it still opens the highlighted file in the main window. How does one open the bookmark?

Comment: Found the answer. The `Space` key does it.

Comment: @PetrDoležal The `Space` side pane select shortcut doesn't appear to work in Gnome 42. Ctrl + Space opens a new window.

Comment: Files 42.2 :  `F6` + focus on the side pane : `SPACE` : nop `CTRL+SPACE`, opens a new window within the location, `CTRL+SHIFT+SPACE`, does not open a new window and replaces the current one. I would like to know where is is officialy documented!

Comment: @RudyVissers that should be an answer!

Answer (score 0):

For new comer's reference who is using `GNOME nautilus 45.2.1` and on linux:

1. `f9` to focus on sidebar.
2. use `Tab` or `Shift-Tab` to navigate between items.